# Email signature button not styling once put into Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, signature

I'm trying to make a simple button that will display in an email signature, using inline CSS. It's working fine when opening in a browser, but when put into Outlook it's not styling correctly.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Here's what it looks like once it's copied into Outlook:

[image]

I'm guessing that because I have to literally copy/paste the signature from a web browser (once opening the html file) to the signature box in Outlook, the inline CSS is not compatible with Outlook's text editor.

This is the inline CSS I'm using, is there a better way I could do it? The signature template is using Tables.

```
<style="color:#fff; text-decoration: none; background: #1a8fce; 
padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a helpful link for this issue. Outlook is very picky on how you style it.
https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design

Here's a code example of how to fix it. You may have to tweak it a bit:

```
<!--[if mso]>
   <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://litmus.com" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#EB7035" fillcolor="#EB7035">
      <w:anchorlock/>
      <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">I am a button &rarr;</center>
    </v:roundrect>
 <![endif]-->
```